# date and time loop for display

Tags: php, loops, date, time

I am stuck at a point and need help, I have a form which have radio buttons for date and time. User select appropriate date and time from the list and click next. These date and times are showed by using an API. Below is the code

```
<?php

foreach($sessions as $session){
                            $parts = explode("T",$session >Session_dtmDate_Time);
                            $sessiondt = $parts[0];
                            $parts2 = explode("-",$parts[1]);
                            $sessiondt .= " ".$parts2[0];

$to = date_create($sessiondt);
$tic_to= $to->format('h:i A, D, d-M-Y');
?>

 <input type="radio" name="sessionid" value="<?php echo $session->Session_strID; ?>" ><?php echo $tic_to; ?>

<?php

}

?>
```

Its out put is as under against each radio button

```
09:15 PM, Thu, 07-Jul-2016
04:00 PM, Fri, 08-Jul-2016
08:45 PM, Fri, 08-Jul-2016
03:15 PM, Sat, 09-Jul-2016
07:15 PM, Sat, 09-Jul-2016
03:15 PM, Sun, 10-Jul-2016
07:15 PM, Sun, 10-Jul-2016
```

but i want to change this display as under with heading as day and date

```
 Thu, 07-Jul-2016

      09:15PM

 Fri, 08-Jul-2016

      04:00PM
      08:45PM

 Sat, 09-Jul-2016  

      03:15PM
      07:15PM

 Sun, 10-Jul-2016

      03:15PM
      07:15PM
```

I dont want to repeat the date with each session. there will be a check box with each session of a day. or anyone know better representation of this then please share

Comment: make array `$tic_to[$to->format('D, d-M-Y')][]= $to->format('h:i A');` and output it

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the date of each of your iterations, and only print the date if it changes.

Something like:

```
$currentDay = null;
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $day = $date->format('D, d-m-Y');
    if($day !== $currentDay) {
        $currentDay = $day;
        echo $day.'<br>';
    }

    echo $date->format('h:i');
}
```